# ES6 (browser), how to get class constructor string to parse its params?

Tags: class, ecmascript-6, cross-browser, tostring

I'd like to ask how to parse ES6 class constructor in order to get its params. I have it done in ES5 (where classes are directly implemented as functions and it works like charm) but for es6 it has changed. let me explain:

when i have following code:

```
class test {

   constructor(a, b, c) {
   }

}

console.log(test.toString());
```

i would expect it would return:

```
function(a, b, c) {
}
```

what is actually true for Firefox, but unfortunately, Chrome, Edge, Opera, Safari returns

```
class test {

   constructor(a, b, c) {
   }

}
```

Its still a function, I am pretty sure about it because

```
typeof (test)
```

returns "function"

but it seems its impossible to get constructor's parameters (or better said, its string representation) anymore.

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uej82nmr/

Ofcourse, I can parse the class string, look for constructor and get its parameters, but... it's not that nice anymore.

Is there simple way how to get class constructor as string in es6?

Comment: In short: don't. What do you need this for?

Comment: Case A: deploy a full ES6 parser to do the job, if you need it done properly. Case B: Just adjust your regex to find the parameter list that follows the string `constructor`, as good as you need it

Comment: I need it for configurable DI container. I mean to assign correct params to correct positions. If there is no other way I'll parse whole class (look for constructor as Bergi said)

Comment: Do not rely on parameter names for DI. Declare them explicitly with strings.

Comment: I have two things: parameter mappings: { c: "paramc", a: "parama", b: "paramb" } and constructor with params (a, b, c). Currently (with es5) I do: get names of params in object and map their values to correct position of constructor param. Works well and its pretty effective, without using of strings and pushing developers to follow the order. I want to avoid strings everywhere where possible. Can't see any reason why I should use them here if its possible without them.

Comment: 1) `Function.prototype.toString` is (or: was) not a required feature for ES implementations 2) minifiers will mess with your parameter names. It's just fragile code.

Comment: Its much better with strings...

Comment: Relying on `.toString` is not recommended. Introspection based on string representation is extremely bad form.